# Segmentation fault when accessing statically initialized __thread variable

Tags: c++, linux, thread-local

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__thread bool foo = true;

int
main() {
    printf("foo = %d\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run with:

```
$ g++ tls.cpp -o tls -o tls
$ ./tls
```

On some systems -- such as Amazon Linux 2013.09.0, ami-5b792c32, kernel 3.4.62-53.42.amzn1.i686, g++ 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) -- this results in a segmentation fault as soon as `foo` is accessed.

On the other hand, explicitly initializing `foo` in code does not result in a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__thread bool foo = true;

int
main() {
    foo = true;  /* Added!! */
    printf("foo = %d\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first code example crash on some system, while the latter does not? Is static initialization of __thread variables not supposed to work? May the operating system be broken?

Comment: Look: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=731228  seems to be a gcc 4.6 problem.

Comment: There are half a dozen similar reports talking about segfaults. I'd try if choosing a larger type (maybe `int`) works, and otherwise try using a more recent GCC.

Comment: That worked wonderfully. Thanks Damon!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell the compiler you want threads support. Most likely, the flag is `-pthread`.

Comment: Sure about that? You need special compiler flags to use a standard C++11 keyword? I'd be surprised if that was the case (though honestly I've never used or cared about `__thread` so I wouldn't know).

Comment: @Damon This is not a standard C++11 keyword. I think you were thinking about thread_local. __thread, as far as I know, is a GNU extension. I'll try out -pthread, I didn't even know that is necessary on Linux.

Comment: No dice. Compiling with -pthread didn't make a difference. Neither did linking to -lpthread.